# AttributeError: 'dict_values' object has no attribute 'get'

Tags: python-3.x, recursion

I have a coding-recursion question, where I am trying to write a recursive function which return only `PscPowerCableConnected` in this case. if anyone have cleaner working code please share it with me.

python3 code

```
def find_intresting_events(processed_events):
    INTERESTED_EVENTS = [
    'PscPowerCableDisconnected',
    'PscPowerCableConnected'
    ]
    for event in INTERESTED_EVENTS:
        if type(processed_events) == list:
            find_intresting_events(processed_events[0])
        else:
            print(processed_events)
            if processed_events.get(event):
                return event
            else:
                find_intresting_events(processed_events.values())
    return None
```

input

```
path = [{'allEvents': [{'type': 'error_recovered', 'data': [{'error_name': 'Power cable connection', 'PscPowerCableConnected': {'error_name': 'Power cable connection', 'steps': {}}}]}], 'id': '5d154ec80df300000006', 'timestamp': 1561677512101, 'ms_since_boot': 10821695}]
```

Error

```
>>> find_intresting_events(path)
{'allEvents': [{'type': 'error_recovered', 'data': [{'error_name': 'Power cable connection', 'PscPowerCableConnected': {'error_name': 'Power cable connection', 'steps': {}}}]}], 'id': '5d154ec80df300000006', 'timestamp': 1561677512101, 'ms_since_boot': 10821695}
dict_values([[{'type': 'error_recovered', 'data': [{'error_name': 'Power cable connection', 'PscPowerCableConnected': {'error_name': 'Power cable connection', 'steps': {}}}]}], '5d154ec80df300000006', 1561677512101, 10821695])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 8, in find_intresting_events
  File "<stdin>", line 14, in find_intresting_events
  File "<stdin>", line 11, in find_intresting_events
AttributeError: 'dict_values' object has no attribute 'get'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to come up with a solution, but it looks ugly. I am sure there are much better way to implement this if you can think of a better way please share it with me.

```
def find_intresting_events(processed_events):
        INTERESTED_EVENTS = [
        'PscPowerCableDisconnected',
        'PscPowerCableConnected'
        ]
        for event in INTERESTED_EVENTS:
            if type(processed_events) == list:
                return find_intresting_events(processed_events[0])
            elif type(processed_events) == dict:
                for k,v in processed_events.items():
                    if type(v) == list:
                        return find_intresting_events(v[0])
                if processed_events.get(event):
                    return event
        return
```

Answer (score 0):

it's happening because you are trying to use **.get** on a **string**, your `if statement` only check that if your data type is a **list**, which **event** variable in your `for loop` is a **string**, so after checking the `if statement` it goes to `else` and it tries  to use `get` method on a string.
you will notice your problem if only you put `print(type(event))` in your first line of your loop.

```
def find_intresting_events(processed_events):
INTERESTED_EVENTS = [
    'PscPowerCableDisconnected',
    'PscPowerCableConnected'
]
for event in INTERESTED_EVENTS:
    if type(processed_events) == list:
        find_intresting_events(processed_events[0])
    else:
        print(type(event))
return None


find_intresting_events(path)
```

the output is:

```
<class 'str'>
<class 'str'>
<class 'str'>
<class 'str'>
```

if you need any further help, I will be happy to help.